# How to get max date from two columns, or null if either column is null?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, null

I have two date columns in a MySQL table representing tasks that are worked on by two users.  The date columns record when user 1 agreed to the task and when user 2 agreed to the task, and can be `NULL` if that user hasn't agreed to the task yet.

I want to generate the date task agreed - which should be NULL unless both users have agreed to the task, or the maximum of the two dates if they've both agreed.

So I want a query that produces:

```
user_1_agreed  user_2_agreed  query_result
NULL           NULL           NULL
2014-01-02     NULL           NULL
NULL           2014-03-04     NULL
2014-01-02     2014-03-04     2014-03-04
```

I'm aware of `MAX`, `COALESCE` and `IF`, but I'm having trouble trying to work out how to combine them to give the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`greatest`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function fits your bill perfectly:

```
SELECT GREATEST(user_1_agreed, user_2_agreed)
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: @MahmoudGamal . . . And that is exactly how `greatest()` behaves.  At least in any recent version of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

please try this, it should give you exactly what you want :)

```
select 
    case 
        when user_1_agreed is null then 'null'
        when user_2_agreed is null then 'null'
        when user_1_agreed  > user_2_agreed  then user_1_agreed  
        else user_2_agreed  
    end as finalvalues
from
    my_table
```